# Getting value of JSP data in the controller

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have a table which displays a target group list. A link is there to view each target group. When I click on "view" it goes to the controller where I want to print the particular target group.

How do I pass that particular target group from the target group list in the controller?

This is my JSP:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%> 
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%> 
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title> viewTargetGroupList</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%@include file="content.jsp" %>

     <form:form commandName="targetGroupList" method="post" action="/segmentation-of-customers/viewOneTargetGroup">
        <c:if test = "${not empty targetGroupList }">
        <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>TARGET GROUP ID</th>
                     <th>TARGET GROUP NAME</th>  
                     <th>VIEW</th>
                </tr>
                <c:forEach items="${targetGroupList}" var="targetGroupList">
                    <tr>
                        <td> ${targetGroupList.targetGroupId}</td>
                         <td> ${targetGroupList.targetGroupName}</td>   
          <a href="/segmentation-of-customers/viewOneTargetGroup"> View</a>
    </tr>
                </c:forEach>

            </table>
        </c:if>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="VIEW TARGET GROUP"></input>
    </form:form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to viewOneTargetGroup new prarmeter `groupId` and sent the relevant Id in JSP:

```
      <a href="/segmentation-of-customers/viewOneTargetGroup?groupId${targetGroupList.targetGroupId}"> View</a>
</tr>
```